# Meteor CollectionFS / GridFS verify correct upload of a file

Tags: meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

In our Meteor App we sometimes run into the issue, after uploading a file that the generated download link is `.../null` and the file is not retrievable anymore or never was uploaded correctly.

There are no errors logged at all.

```
FileUploads.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {

  if (err) { // this error never triggers
    log(err);
  } else {
    if(fileObj.isUploaded()) { // is true after correct or non correct upload
      FileUploads.find(fileObj._id); // fetches correct metadata even if file upload was corrupt
      if(fileObj.url()=== 'null') {
         throw Meteor.Error(...) // never thrown even when URL was "null"
      }

    }   
  }
```

List of used cfs packages:

```
cfs:access-point@0.1.49_2
cfs:base-package@0.0.30
cfs:collection@0.5.5
cfs:collection-filters@0.2.4
cfs:data-man@0.0.6
cfs:file@0.1.17
cfs:gridfs@0.0.34
cfs:http-methods@0.0.32
cfs:http-publish@0.0.13
cfs:power-queue@0.9.11
cfs:reactive-list@0.0.9
cfs:reactive-property@0.0.4
cfs:standard-packages@0.5.10
cfs:storage-adapter@0.2.4
cfs:tempstore@0.1.6
cfs:upload-http@0.0.20
cfs:worker@0.1.5
```

So how can we make sure the file was uploaded correctly right after an upload?
`fileObj,isUploaded()` seems not reliable. Is there a better way to verify the correct upload?

Comment: Which package you actually use for files?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I have added a list of the cfs packages we use